# OS Keeping On Same Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive

IS it possible to keep my Windows 7 and Linux OS's on the same hard drive?
And able to choose what to use OS to use when I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its called dual-booting see here how to dual boot http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Comment: Does Ubuntu have to be installed

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, the question is duplicate.

Comment: yes ubuntu need to be installed

Comment: Do I need to install ubuntu on my hard drive or can I use a bootable USB stick.\

Comment: And then install it.

Comment: you should use bootable usb and then install it. Before installing create a separate partition for ubuntu